# getting short lived token via php sdk v4 API call

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

What should be the $session in the following code

```
$request = new FacebookRequest(
  $session,
  'GET',
  '/{page-id}?fields=access_token'
);
```

If I use following, id is the only output I am getting.

```
$session = FacebookSession::newAppSession();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you get the id only, it´s most likely a problem with the permissions.

Make sure you requested the `manage_pages` permission in your login code (you do have a login code, right?), and make sure you are trying with an Admin of the App - else you would have to let Facebook approve the permission before you can use it for any User.

Without login, you can only use an App Access Token.

Some important links about the different Access Tokens and how to get them:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/extended-page-access-tokens-curl/

Comment: My app is to display my fan page's ratings in my website. No one logs into it. Earlier I used short lived token from Graph Explorer and generated never expire token from it and used it. Then when I changed my password It's gone. So i'm trying to get a page access token from API call rather than Graph Explorer. I only have app id and app secret.

Comment: well....no login, no access token, of course. the only access token usable without login is an app access token - and you you will not get a page access token with that one.

Comment: Is there any way to auto login as admin, and get page access token?

Comment: auto login? what do you mean? a login always has to be initiated by a user.

Comment: take a look at the links i posted, especially the parts about extended page access tokens. you only need to login with an admin once, get the extended page token, store it and you will be fine. the extended page token is valid forever.